# What are the subscribed topics of local planner from global planner?

Tags: ros, navigation, base-global-planner, ros-indigo, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Who generates > `nav_msg/Path`  local planner or global planner? If it is generated by global_planner then how local planner use it to avoid obstacle. Can we generate customized nav_msg/Path?? Actually how exactly the communication happens between global planner and local planner, using what topics or messages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282519/what-are-the-subscribed-topics-of-local-planner-from-global-planner?/) by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2018-02-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-13**:
I'm not sure, but it seems your question is at least partially answered by [wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) (*Robot Setup* section).

**Comment by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on 2018-02-13**:
Is it black box?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-13**:\

> Is it black box?

I don't understand what you're saying. The diagram under "Robot Setup" shows a (terse) overview of the communication between various parts of the navigation stack. I don't see any black boxes.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-02-13**:
note that global and local planner are plugins that are loaded into a single node, `move_base`. So they don't actually communicate via Topics. They both have a defined API through which the respective Information is passed. They provide Topics e.g. for visualization as well as cmds, but that is it.

**Comment by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on 2018-02-14**:
@mig is it through nav_core interfaces? Is there any extra information available on internet, journal or any book?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-02-15**:
Use Google:

- http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS
- https://www.springerprofessional.de/writing-global-path-planners-plugins-in-ros-a-tutorial/7458334

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-15**:
@mig: ROS Answers is for (new) users to get some guidance on how to approach and/or solve their problem(s).

Your contributions are very much appreciated, but I assume that if @mallikarjun knew what to search for he would've done that.

Perhaps you could extend your comment a bit and post an answer?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-02-15**:
@gvdhoorn @mallikarjun sorry, if my comment was a bit harsh. it wasn't intended to be like that.

**Comment by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on 2018-02-15**:
@mig @gvdhoorn Thank you for your replies. I am new to ROS and learning everyday, so sometimes I ask foolish question. I am thankful to ROS community for providing this platform, otherwise It would have been very difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll try to answer the questions in order.

All assuming you use the Standard  `move_base` structure as linked to by @gvdhoorn above.

> Who generates > nav_msg/Path local planner or global planner?

Both, but actually just for visualization. Typically on something like `move_base/<PLANNER>/<local_/global_>plan` topics. The local planner also generates a `geometry_msgs/Twist` message which provides the commanded velocities to the robot.

> If it is generated by global_planner then how local planner use it to avoid obstacle.

It is passed from the global planner to the local planner through the [`nav_core` Interfaces](http://wiki.ros.org/nav_core?distro=lunar).

> Can we generate customized nav_msg/Path??

Sure, as both `local_planners` and `global_planners` are [plugins](http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib) to `move_base` you can write your own plugin which creates the plan in a way that you want. Some more Information about how to do this can be found [in the Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS) or [here](https://www.springerprofessional.de/writing-global-path-planners-plugins-in-ros-a-tutorial/7458334), for example.

> Actually how exactly the communication happens between global planner and local planner, using what topics or messages?

As stated above, this happens through the defined [`nav_core` interfaces](http://wiki.ros.org/nav_core?distro=lunar). For more Details, please refer to the API documentation on the wiki page.

> Is it black box?

No, as this is, as all of ROS, OSS. Check the links to the API documentation as well as the github repos on the respective wiki pages.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on 2018-02-15**:
Thank you very much.